# How do I compress an image with Run-Length Encoding using C#?

Tags: c#, image, compression, image-compression

How do I compress an image with Run-Length Encoding using C#? Are there any available libraries to support this?

Does Run-Length Encoding only work on bitmapped images? If so, How will I convert image types to bitmap using C#?

I'd also like to ask what's their resulting file type after this, will they retain their file type or will they have a new one?

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why this question is voted down? Under what terms?

Comment: I am going to guess lack of research.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Comment: I'm really wondering why someone would bother with the internals of image compression inside generally used formats. Might as well just take png then. _Is_ RLE-compressed BMP even a generally-supported format? I know it's an option inside DIB, but that doesn't guarantee much.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but it is one of the few things that comes up for RLE compression in C# on Google search. For someone like me, who has no experience with image processing at all, this was a very frustrating experience, so hopefully this answer will save some others pain in the future.

I understand that RLE is an out-dated form of compression, but some of us are stuck with constraints (such as exporting a bmp to a custom device) that require us to use it. The following requires an 8bpp indexed bitmap in order to work. If you need help converting an image to that format, there are a good number of resources online to help out.

I put this inside a class called BmpCompressor.

```
private enum Compression
    {
        // others not necessary for the 8bpp compression, but left for reference
        //BI_RGB = 0x0000,
        BI_RLE8 = 0x0001,
        //BI_RLE4 = 0x0002,
        //BI_BITFIELDS = 0x0003,
        //BI_JPEG = 0x0004,
        //BI_PNG = 0x0005,
        //BI_CMYK = 0x000B,
        //BI_CMYKRLE8 = 0x000C,
        //BI_CMYKRLE4 = 0x000D
    }

    private enum BitCount
    {
        // others not necessary for the 8bpp compression, but left for reference
        //Undefined = (ushort)0x0000,
        //TwoColors = (ushort)0x0001,
        //Max16Colors = (ushort)0x0004,
        Max256Colors = (ushort)0x0008,
        //Max32KBColors = (ushort)0x0010,
        //Max16MBColors = (ushort)0x0018,
        //Max16MBColors_Compressed = (ushort)0x0020
    }

    private struct RleCompressedBmpHeader
    {
        // Everything before the HeaderSize is technically not part of the header (it's not included in the HeaderSize calculation)

        /// <summary>
        /// Size of the .bmp file.
        /// Always header size (40), plus palette size, plus image size, plus pre-header size (14);
        /// </summary>
        public uint Size;

        /// <summary>
        /// Offset to start of image data in bytes from the start of the file
        /// </summary>
        public uint Offset;

        /// <summary>
        /// Size of this header in bytes. (Always 40)
        /// </summary>
        public uint HeaderSize; // 4 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4

        /// <summary>
        /// Width of bitmap in pixels
        /// </summary>
        public int Width;

        /// <summary>
        /// Height of bitmap in pixels
        /// </summary>
        public int Height;

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of Planes (layers). Always 1.
        /// </summary>
        public ushort Planes;
        /// <summary>
        /// Number of bits that define each pixel and maximum number of colors
        /// </summary>
        public BitCount BitCount;

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the compression mode of the bitmap.
        /// </summary>
        public Compression Compression;

        /// <summary>
        /// Size, in bytes, of image.
        /// </summary>
        public uint ImageSize;

        // These shouldn't really be all that important
        public uint XPixelsPerMeter;
        public uint YPixelsPerMeter;

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of indexes in the color table used by this bitmap.
        /// <para>0 - Use max available</para>
        /// <para>If BitCount is less than 16, this is the number of colors used by the bitmap</para>
        /// <para>If BitCount is 16 or greater, this specifies the size of the color table used to optimize performance of the system palette.</para>
        /// </summary>
        public uint ColorUsed;

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of color indexes that are required for displaying the bitmap. 0 means all color indexes are required.
        /// </summary>
        public uint ColorImportant;

        public byte[] ToBytes()
        {
            var swap = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian;
            var result = new List<byte>();

            result.AddRange(new byte[] { 0x42, 0x4d }); // signature (BM)
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Size));
            result.AddRange(new byte[4]); // reserved
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Offset));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(HeaderSize));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Width));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Height));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Planes));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)BitCount));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)Compression));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(ImageSize));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(XPixelsPerMeter));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(YPixelsPerMeter));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(ColorUsed));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(ColorImportant));

            return result.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public unsafe byte[] RunLengthEncodeBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        if (bmp.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed) { throw new ArgumentException("The image must be in 8bppIndexed PixelFormat", "bmp"); }

        var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

        // Actual RLE algorithm. Bottom of image is first stored row, so start from bottom.
        for (var rowIndex = bmp.Height - 1; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
        {
            byte? storedPixel = null;
            var curPixelRepititions = 0;
            var imageRow = (byte*)data.Scan0.ToPointer() + (rowIndex * data.Stride);
            for (var pixelIndex = 0; pixelIndex < bmp.Width; pixelIndex++)
            {
                var curPixel = imageRow[pixelIndex];
                if (!storedPixel.HasValue)
                {
                    curPixelRepititions = 1;
                    storedPixel = curPixel;
                }
                else if (storedPixel.Value != curPixel || curPixelRepititions == 255)
                {
                    result.Add(Convert.ToByte(curPixelRepititions));
                    result.Add(storedPixel.Value);
                    curPixelRepititions = 1;
                    storedPixel = curPixel;
                }
                else
                {
                    curPixelRepititions++;
                }
            }

            if (curPixelRepititions > 0)
            {
                result.Add(Convert.ToByte(curPixelRepititions));
                result.Add(storedPixel.Value);
            }

            if (rowIndex == 0)
            {
                // EOF flag
                result.Add(0x00);
                result.Add(0x01);
            }
            else
            {
                // End of Line Flag
                result.Add(0x00);
                result.Add(0x00);
            }
        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        var paletteSize = (uint)bmp.Palette.Entries.Length * 4;
        var header = new RleCompressedBmpHeader();
        header.HeaderSize = 40;
        header.Size = header.HeaderSize + paletteSize + (uint)result.Count + 14;
        header.Offset = header.HeaderSize + 14 + paletteSize; // total header size + palette size
        header.Width = bmp.Width;
        header.Height = bmp.Height;
        header.Planes = 1;
        header.BitCount = BitCount.Max256Colors;
        // as far as I can tell, PixelsPerMeter are not terribly important
        header.XPixelsPerMeter = 0x10000000;
        header.YPixelsPerMeter = 0x10000000;
        header.Compression = Compression.BI_RLE8;
        header.ColorUsed = 256;
        header.ColorImportant = 0; // use all available colors
        header.ImageSize = header.HeaderSize + (uint)result.Count;

        var headerBytes = header.ToBytes();
        var paletteBytes = ConvertPaletteToBytes(bmp.Palette);

        return headerBytes.Concat(paletteBytes).Concat(result).ToArray();
    }

    private byte[] ConvertPaletteToBytes(ColorPalette colorPalette)
    {
        return colorPalette.Entries.SelectMany(c => new byte[]
            {
                c.B,
                c.G,
                c.R,
                0
            }).ToArray();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please post an implementation of bmp decompression? I've tried to implement, but it's not working =(

Answer (score 0):

If you look around you will find quite a few resources...

[Run length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_length_encoding) works on just about any type of data in the form of a string.

But here is an example from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#C.23):

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string input = "WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW";
       Console.WriteLine(Encode(input));//Outputs: 12W1B12W3B24W1B14W
       Console.WriteLine(Decode(Encode(input)));//Outputs: WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
   public static string Encode(string s)
   {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       int count = 1;
       char current =s[0];
       for(int i = 1; i < s.Length;i++)
       {
           if (current == s[i])
           {
               count++;
           }
           else
           {
               sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", count, current);
               count = 1;
               current = s[i];
           }
       }
       sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", count, current);
       return sb.ToString();
   }
   public static string Decode(string s)
   {
       string a = "";
       int count = 0;
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       char current = char.MinValue;
       for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
       {
           current = s[i];
           if (char.IsDigit(current))
               a += current;
           else
           {
               count = int.Parse(a);
               a = "";
               for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                   sb.Append(current);
           }
       }
       return sb.ToString();
   }
```

You will have to suit this to your needs but it should get you started.

Comment: RLE isn't limited to strings at all, and the question was a binary case, since it was about bitmap data...

Answer (score -3):

To compress an image I have written some function:
This will resize the width and determine the height by aspect ratio. Note that if the original width of the image is less than the new width then the image is not sized (you can definitely change that in the code).

```
    public Bitmap ResizedImage(Stream imageStream, int newWidth)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
        int newwidthimg = image.Size.Width;
        int newheightimg = image.Size.Height;
        if (newWidth <= image.Size.Width)
        {
            newwidthimg = newWidth;
            float AspectRatio = (float)image.Size.Width / (float)image.Size.Height;
            newheightimg = Convert.ToInt32(newwidthimg / AspectRatio);
        }
        Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = new Bitmap(newwidthimg, newheightimg);
        using (Graphics thumbnailGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailBitmap))
        {
            thumbnailGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            thumbnailGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            thumbnailGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newwidthimg, newheightimg);
            thumbnailGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
        }
        return thumbnailBitmap;
```

Comment: This is not run length encoding.

Comment: This is shrinking an image and doesn't answer the question.