# Compressing a bitmap with Run Length Encoding [RLE] using GDI+

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+, encoder

I tried a lot searching on Google before posting this question here.
I want to compress a 8bpp Bitmap using RLE [Run Length Encoding] compression in my Win forms application.
Most of the results I found were from VC++ code, Can I do perform compression using GDI+ ? does GDI+ provide any such classes or methods ?
I found one link on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but It doesn't helped much.

Also, I tried to write below code using "System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder" but the output image
has the same size.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap myBitmap;
    ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
    Encoder myEncoder;
    EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
    EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;

    // Create a Bitmap object based on a BMP file.
    myBitmap = new Bitmap("D:\\8BppImage.bmp");

    // Get an ImageCodecInfo object that represents the bmp codec.
    myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/bmp");

    // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID 
    // for the Compression parameter category.
    myEncoder = Encoder.Compression;

    // Create an EncoderParameters object. 
    myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(
        myEncoder,(long)EncoderValue.CompressionRle);

    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

    myBitmap.Save("D:\\EncoderImg.bmp", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);

}

private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
{
    int j;
    ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
    encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
    {
        if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
            return encoders[j];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Am I missing something ? can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: You get the same size because RLE is not BMP and the former does not compress. As you pointed out like here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/04/08/9537051.aspx it can be done in C++, maybe you can Pinvoke GetDIBits ? On the other hand the link you sent explains the format, you can make it by yourself.

Comment: RLE compression is widely ignored, there's just no point to it with real compression algorithms widely available.  PNG is a much better format.

Answer (score 3):

I've submitted an answer to compressing 8bpp images in C# using RLE on this question: [How do I compress an image with Run-Length Encoding using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822274/how-do-i-compress-an-image-with-run-length-encoding-using-c/26717454#26717454)

I believe what you are attempting does not work because the EncoderValue.CompressionRle only applies to .TIFF images.

Here is the code that was used to perform compression:

```
    private enum Compression
    {
        // others not necessary for the 8bpp compression, but left for reference
        //BI_RGB = 0x0000,
        BI_RLE8 = 0x0001,
        //BI_RLE4 = 0x0002,
        //BI_BITFIELDS = 0x0003,
        //BI_JPEG = 0x0004,
        //BI_PNG = 0x0005,
        //BI_CMYK = 0x000B,
        //BI_CMYKRLE8 = 0x000C,
        //BI_CMYKRLE4 = 0x000D
    }

    private enum BitCount
    {
        // others not necessary for the 8bpp compression, but left for reference
        //Undefined = (ushort)0x0000,
        //TwoColors = (ushort)0x0001,
        //Max16Colors = (ushort)0x0004,
        Max256Colors = (ushort)0x0008,
        //Max32KBColors = (ushort)0x0010,
        //Max16MBColors = (ushort)0x0018,
        //Max16MBColors_Compressed = (ushort)0x0020
    }

    private struct RleCompressedBmpHeader
    {
        // Everything before the HeaderSize is technically not part of the header (it's not included in the HeaderSize calculation)

        /// <summary>
        /// Size of the .bmp file.
        /// Always header size (40), plus palette size, plus image size, plus pre-header size (14);
        /// </summary>
        public uint Size;

        /// <summary>
        /// Offset to start of image data in bytes from the start of the file
        /// </summary>
        public uint Offset;

        /// <summary>
        /// Size of this header in bytes. (Always 40)
        /// </summary>
        public uint HeaderSize; // 4 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4

        /// <summary>
        /// Width of bitmap in pixels
        /// </summary>
        public int Width;

        /// <summary>
        /// Height of bitmap in pixels
        /// </summary>
        public int Height;

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of Planes (layers). Always 1.
        /// </summary>
        public ushort Planes;
        /// <summary>
        /// Number of bits that define each pixel and maximum number of colors
        /// </summary>
        public BitCount BitCount;

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the compression mode of the bitmap.
        /// </summary>
        public Compression Compression;

        /// <summary>
        /// Size, in bytes, of image.
        /// </summary>
        public uint ImageSize;

        // These shouldn't really be all that important
        public uint XPixelsPerMeter;
        public uint YPixelsPerMeter;

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of indexes in the color table used by this bitmap.
        /// <para>0 - Use max available</para>
        /// <para>If BitCount is less than 16, this is the number of colors used by the bitmap</para>
        /// <para>If BitCount is 16 or greater, this specifies the size of the color table used to optimize performance of the system palette.</para>
        /// </summary>
        public uint ColorUsed;

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of color indexes that are required for displaying the bitmap. 0 means all color indexes are required.
        /// </summary>
        public uint ColorImportant;

        public byte[] ToBytes()
        {
            var swap = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian;
            var result = new List<byte>();

            result.AddRange(new byte[] { 0x42, 0x4d }); // signature (BM)
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Size));
            result.AddRange(new byte[4]); // reserved
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Offset));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(HeaderSize));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Width));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Height));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Planes));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)BitCount));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)Compression));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(ImageSize));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(XPixelsPerMeter));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(YPixelsPerMeter));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(ColorUsed));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(ColorImportant));

            return result.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public unsafe byte[] RunLengthEncodeBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        if (bmp.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed) { throw new ArgumentException("The image must be in 8bppIndexed PixelFormat", "bmp"); }

        var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

        // Actual RLE algorithm. Bottom of image is first stored row, so start from bottom.
        for (var rowIndex = bmp.Height - 1; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
        {
            byte? storedPixel = null;
            var curPixelRepititions = 0;
            var imageRow = (byte*)data.Scan0.ToPointer() + (rowIndex * data.Stride);
            for (var pixelIndex = 0; pixelIndex < bmp.Width; pixelIndex++)
            {
                var curPixel = imageRow[pixelIndex];
                if (!storedPixel.HasValue)
                {
                    curPixelRepititions = 1;
                    storedPixel = curPixel;
                }
                else if (storedPixel.Value != curPixel || curPixelRepititions == 255)
                {
                    result.Add(Convert.ToByte(curPixelRepititions));
                    result.Add(storedPixel.Value);
                    curPixelRepititions = 1;
                    storedPixel = curPixel;
                }
                else
                {
                    curPixelRepititions++;
                }
            }

            if (curPixelRepititions > 0)
            {
                result.Add(Convert.ToByte(curPixelRepititions));
                result.Add(storedPixel.Value);
            }

            if (rowIndex == 0)
            {
                // EOF flag
                result.Add(0x00);
                result.Add(0x01);
            }
            else
            {
                // End of Line Flag
                result.Add(0x00);
                result.Add(0x00);
            }
        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        var paletteSize = (uint)bmp.Palette.Entries.Length * 4;
        var header = new RleCompressedBmpHeader();
        header.HeaderSize = 40;
        header.Size = header.HeaderSize + paletteSize + (uint)result.Count + 14;
        header.Offset = header.HeaderSize + 14 + paletteSize; // total header size + palette size
        header.Width = bmp.Width;
        header.Height = bmp.Height;
        header.Planes = 1;
        header.BitCount = BitCount.Max256Colors;
        // as far as I can tell, PixelsPerMeter are not terribly important
        header.XPixelsPerMeter = 0x10000000;
        header.YPixelsPerMeter = 0x10000000;
        header.Compression = Compression.BI_RLE8;
        header.ColorUsed = 256;
        header.ColorImportant = 0; // use all available colors
        header.ImageSize = header.HeaderSize + (uint)result.Count;

        var headerBytes = header.ToBytes();
        var paletteBytes = ConvertPaletteToBytes(bmp.Palette);

        return headerBytes.Concat(paletteBytes).Concat(result).ToArray();
    }

    private byte[] ConvertPaletteToBytes(ColorPalette colorPalette)
    {
        return colorPalette.Entries.SelectMany(c => new byte[]
            {
                c.B,
                c.G,
                c.R,
                0
            }).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NiklasRingdahl fair enough, I've added the code example I provided in the other answer.